# Excel data manipulation with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm working on a task to extract all users from x DL and export it to an excel file for it to be used in a future for another import task. I'm trying to wrap the emails with double quotes when exporting it to excel but for some reason is not showing whatsoever the weird thing is that if i open the same file with a text editor it will show there.

```
$DL = "DLNAME"
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$DL" -Recursive 
Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |
Select-Object Mail |
Export-CSV -Path C:\file1.csv -Usequotes always
```

Comment: `Export-Csv` exports using quotes by default this is so the CSV can be interpreted correctly by any spreadsheet application if a value on a row has a comma in it. You would see the commas include with the delimiters if you open it with a plain text editor such as notepad but this wouldn't be the case if you open the CSV with a spreadsheet app (as mentioned above) and you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, if you actually want to add another layer of quotes, meaning they would be visible in a spreadsheet app, you can use a calculated property like this `Select-Object @{ n='Mail'; e={ '"' + $_.Mail + '"' }`

Comment: I need the emails to be double quoted in excel and is not showing when i export the file, also i tried that string and is returning with an error message

Comment: Try `Select-Object @{Name = 'Mail'; Expression = {'"{0}"' -f $_.Mail}}`. Works for me